# Dex graph database retrieve all nodes and edges

Tags: c#, graph-databases

I know how I can output my graph database to a file (like a GraphML file), but I'd rather iterate through the nodes and have them as C# objects because I need to use them elsewhere.

Something like this:

```
var it = graph.GetNodeIterator();
while (it.HasNext()) {
    var node = new MyNodeObject();
    //get attributes or whatever
    nodeList.Add(node);
}
//nodeList now contains all nodes in a List
```

I can't find a convenient way to do this and the Dex documentation isn't very helpful. Clearly Dex has some way of doing this because I can easily export to GraphML, but I don't want to export to GraphML and then parse the GraphML into C# objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do it, not sure if it's the best way though:

```
//find the type(s) youre looking for based on how you assigned
//them in the first place. you may already know.
var typeIt = graph.FindTypes().Iterator();
while (typeIt.HasNext()) {
   //find your types if you dont know
}

//select the types you want. lets say all of your nodes have one of two types,
//which map to attributes 4 and 3.
var select = graph.Select(4);
//union them
select.Union(graph.Select(3));
//start to iterate
var it = select.Iterator();
while (it.HasNext()) {
    var next = it.Next();
    //map to your own objects using next
}
```